# Fastest way to compare two matrices element by element

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix of some values between 0 and 1:

```
values = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dx, dy}]
```

Now I want to "binarize them", ie compare them to some random probabilities - if greater, return 1, else, return 0. Here are some ways to do this:

```
Boole[MapThread[#1 > #2 &, {values, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {dx, dy}]}, 2]]
```

Or:

```
Table[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1, values[[i, j]]]], {i, 1, dx}, {j, 1, dy}]
```

What are some others, and what is the fastest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fastest is likely `UnitStep[a-b]` where `a` is your matrix, and `b` is either a scalar to compare to or another matrix of the same dimensions. This will give `1`s where `a >= b`.

My [BoolEval package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/BoolEval) allows for nicer notation, especially when the operation you want is not exactly `>=`.

```
BoolEval[a >= b]
```

Comment: Just in case, `Sign` seems to be about as fast as `UnitStep`, but returns values in $\{-1,1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Wow, that is fast! Thanks